# Generate Firebase cloud messaging server token

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any API (Python, JS, ...) that can be used to generate and retrieve the Firebase cloud messaging server token?

The end goal should be the same as clicking the [Add server key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpgkZ.png) button in the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to generate that key outside of the Firebase console.

Maybe have a look at the [FCM HTTP v1 API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) which uses an OAuth based security model where the short lived tokens can be generated server side.